# How to Modify the Font Size of the Contents in a Table

Tags: php, html, css, fonts, html-table

In my table I am trying to change the font size. I have tried adding font size in the tag, adding it in the CSS code for the Myposts class, but nothing prevailed. How can I change the font size?

```
  <table width="100%" border="0" class = "Myposts"; align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1"  bgcolor="#686868 " >
  <tr>
   <td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#505050 " ><strong>#</strong></td>
   <td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#505050 "><strong>Job Description</strong></td>
   <td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#505050 "><strong>Views</strong></td>
   <td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#505050 "><strong>Replies</strong></td>
   <td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#505050 "><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select table cells in CSS

```
table.Myposts tr td {
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Myposts td {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wk28Y/

Comment: Oh, so you have to specify td? Got it now! Thank you so much! That's why I wasn't getting a result.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't consider this an answer, just a different way of thinking about the issue. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KghK4/)

You could get rid of the "bold" line by making the first row `<th>` instead of `<td>`.

Add the css table styling to your Myposts class.

You note in the title that it is php, but I don't see any php tags. So I assume you're passing php to an html page, thus the css styling would still work for you.

HTML

```
<table class = "Myposts">
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>Job Description</td>
    <td>Views</td>
    <td>Replies</td>
    <td>Date/Time</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: #686868;
  border-spacing: 1px;
}
table td {
  background-color: #505050;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 6%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 53%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 15%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 13%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(5) {
  width: 13%;
}
```